# OData $top query in LINQ expression could not be transalted and will be evaluated locally using EF Core and .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, odata

I have an OData endpoint in my .NET Core API:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute]
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<MerchantDto> GetAll()
{
    return _context
        .Merchants
        .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
        .ProjectTo<MerchantDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
}
```

It generates an SQL without `LIMIT` statement (postgres db) and this warning appears:

> The LINQ expression 'Take(__TypedProperty_1)' could not be translated
>   and will be evaluated locally.

How can I make this query to DB to include the OData `$top`? It is always getting the whole table records first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a wrong object mapping configuration that caused that problem.